# Has anybody been able to install Acestream on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit?

Tags: 14.04, 32-bit

I'm trying to follow the instructions on wiziwig.eu but I can't find the dependency packages python2.7-apsw and so forth...

Comment: Please edit and improve your question, by elaboration on `and so forth... ` part. Also see here: https://packages.debian.org/hu/wheezy/python2.7-apsw